# SQL select row dependent on time last chosen

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, select, time

I have a table that looks like this

```
id   |   refreshTime   |   lastRanAt             |   otherFeilds
1    |   60            |   2012-05-14 14:25:08   |   somthing
2    |   30            |   2012-05-14 15:25:08   |   something else
3    |   20            |   2012-05-03 16:25:08   |   foo
```

I would like to return results where the 'lastRanAt' datetime is less than the currentTime minus the refreshTime (the refreshTime is in minutes)

Can this be done in one query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which kind of DB are you using (SQL-Server, Oracle, MySQL, ...)?

Comment: Ah sorry, It's SQL-server I always forget that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select * 
from Table t
where lastRanAt < dateadd(mi, (t.refreshTime * -1), getdate())
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b06c/6)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```
select * 
from your_table
where lastRanAt < dateadd(mi, refreshTime * -1 , getdate())
```

Comment: How would I go about setting the refreshTime? It's different for every row

Comment: you can add the code to a procedure and pass the refreshtime as a parameter

Comment: It is far easier and much faster just to pass the refreshTime field's value. Otherwise you'd have to create a cursor to retrieve the field value for each row then execute the statement.

Comment: true, I did not realize the refresh time was on the table, I thought it was a fixed value. I updated my answer